# Redux: Where to store component configuration for reusability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this problem that I need to reuse this component on two pages. There is some configuration variables that could affect how it behaves. What I am doing now is 
      `<Component config={config} />`
with different config on each page. This component is also connected to the store. Later I find that one of my event handled in the reducer needs to know about the config.

What is the best way to store configuration? Should I have multiple initialState for the reducer and reuse the reducer in two different places in the store for each page like the following.

```
combineReducers({
  page1Widgets: {
     Component: reducer
  },
  page2Widgets: {
     Component: reducer
  }
})

const initialStateByPage = {
  path1: ...,
  path2: ...
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  if (state == null) {
    state = initialStateByPage[location.pathname];
  }
}
```

What is a good way to do this ?

Comment: Does it really need a full configuration object? Have you considered splitting the component?

Comment: Oh the configuration can be just a flag. No need to be an object.  Splitting the component will probably still need to know about the flag.